# No se refresca Datepicker al usar beforeShowDay

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, calendar, jquery-datepicker

Buenos días. Estoy usando datepicker de Jquery UI de la siguiente manera:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
initComponent();
});

var j = 0;
function checkDate(date) {
    j++;
    if (j>5 && j<10)
    {
        return [true, 'event',''];
    }
    else if (j>20 && j<25)
    {
        return [true, 'event2',''];
    }
    else
    {
        return [true,''];
    }

     }

function initComponent(){
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["es"]);
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        firstDay: 1,
        inline: true,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        beforeShowDay: checkDate
    });

}
```

Este código me muestra el calendario del datepicker con distinto estilo las fechas seleccionadas con los estilos event y event2. El problema está en que, una vez cargado el calendario, si selecciono cualquier fecha se borra el estilo que había modificado con beforeShowDay dejando el estilo por defecto en todos los días del mes. He probado con refresh en onSelect pero no me ha funcionado. ¿Sabéis si me falta algo o qué tipo de error estoy cometiendo?

El body del HTML es simplemente:

`<div id="datepicker"></div>`

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Estás determinando el estilo según la variable `j`, que no tiene nada que ver con la fecha.**

Como inicializas `j` en 0, la primera vez que selecciones una fecha, `j` será igual a 1 y tu función retorna que el *datepicker* no debe tener estilo. Si seleccionaras una fecha cinco veces seguidas, probablemente se aplicaría el estilo *event*.

Lo que tiene que hacer tu función (por lo que acabo de buscar), es algo similar a esto:

```
function checkDate(date) {
    var dia = date.getDate();

    if (dia>5 && dia<10)
    {
        return [true, 'event',''];
    }
    else if (dia>20 && dia<25)
    {
        return [true, 'event2',''];
    }
    else
    {
        return [true,''];
    }
}
```

De esta forma, según el día de la fecha seleccionada, determinas el estilo.

**Fuente:** [Respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29122128) en *Stack Overflow*: [JQuery DatePicker and beforeShowDay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484159/jquery-datepicker-and-beforeshowday)

Comment: Llevas toda la razón. Muchas gracias!